# Controlling Multiple Brushless Motors with Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, motor

I'm working on making an FPV racing drone as an introductory project to using Arduino. I need to be able to control four brushless motors using an Arduino Uno.

First of all, does anyone have any recommendations for motor type and ESC type? But my real question is: how can I power all four motors using one battery? What components do I need to buy? I've tried searching the internet for the answer but I can't find my specific use case, although it doesn't seem like it's uncommon at all.

Comment: The uncommon thing in this use case is the Arduino. These days nearly noone uses an Arduino for building a drone. Taking all the sensory input, doing the fusion of the sensor data and controlling the drone accordingly is not a trivial task. A dedicated flight controller is better fit for this task and these days not that expensive. I'm sure, that there are plenty of drone building tutorials on the web, that does not involve Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Arduino really isn't the best processor for a drone. It can certainly be done however. You can [buy a MultiWii flight controller](https://www.readytoflyquads.com/multiwii-pro-flight-controller) which is based around an Arduino Mega and functions as a drone flight controller.

You can't just ask which motors and ESCs to use. How heavy is your drone? How fast does it need to fly? Is there a payload? To figure out which motors to use, go watch some videos by FliteTest or a multitude of other videos online suggesting how to build a drone. You can certainly power everything off one battery. Again, watch some videos on how multirotor drones are made.

Takeway: An Arduino is a very poor choice for making a flight controller, and there quite a few components needed to build a drone, so watch some videos and learn how!